# How to count individual cycles of a 24 GHz clocking signal?

Tags: clock, cmos, counter, pll

Are there digital counters or similar circuits available that can count cycles or even half cycles (e.g., by threshold crossing) of a 24 GHz clocking signal? I am not looking for frequency counters here, but instead for a digital counter that could in principle, given said clock signal, count 1 cycle and therefore resolve time at 42 picoseconds.

Comment: Have you seen [Counter for 20 GHz clock](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/220559/counter-for-20-ghz-clock)?

Comment: In addition to the ideas in that link there are commercial PCIe boards for TOF detection with single digit picosecond time resolution. I suspect they won't be cheap, but an off the shelf solution will be a lot easier.

Comment: As user says: How deep are your pockets?

Comment: Maybe one of [these](https://www.adsantec.com/categories/d-type-flip-flops/)?